# Meteor project update bootstrap-3 to bootstrap-4

Tags: mongodb, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a meteor project. In this project Bootstrap v3 used. now I want to update this project in Bootstrap v4. What the steps I need to do.

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/@g1zmo/bootstrap-4-and-meteor-js-4cec073a4f6c) out.

Answer (score 0):

Bootrap have a migration guide - 
https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/